# Remove autoincrement from postgresql field

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

I have an existing table in a db, FK'd from several others, SQL below:

```
CREATE TABLE forecastsource (
    source_id integer DEFAULT nextval(('public.forecastsource_source_id_seq'::text)::regclass) NOT NULL,
    source_name character varying NOT NULL
);
```

I want to remove the autoincrement from the id field, and just move it to be a int field (without losing the current data in the table). How would I do that, other than dropping and recreating the table?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just drop the default value:

```
ALTER TABLE forecastsource ALTER COLUMN source_id DROP DEFAULT;
```

You probably also want to drop the sequence then.

Comment: If the sequence was created as a SERIAL and you still need it for some reason, you should ALTER SEQUENCE forecastsource_source_id_seq OWNED BY NONE;

Comment: how to remove SEQUENCE from a column by `column_name` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was right solution

```
ALTER TABLE tc_user ALTER COLUMN u_id DROP IDENTITY
```